# returning different return types in scala

Tags: scala

**Is there a way to return different return types from a single method in scala?**

For example, if I have a `load()` method, I would like to return different data types depending on the object that called this method.

```
def load(path: String):<return type> 
{
    // if this instance is of type "type1", do some processing on this object, 
    // and return object of type "type1"

    // else if this instance is of type "type2", do some processing on this object,
    // and return object of type return "type2"
 }
```

Comment: try an [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html) :  `Either[Type1,Type2]`

Comment: Is there any relationship between type1 and type2?

Comment: you can read about `magnet pattern` or `path dependent types`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you want, [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) may work for you:

```
trait Base[T <: Base[T]] {
  def load(path: String): T
}

class Type1 extends Base[Type1] {
  override def load(path: String): Type1 = new Type1 // provisional implementation
}

class Type2 extends Base[Type2] {
  override def load(path: String): Type2 = new Type2
}
```

Then `load` will return the type of the current object. Note the result types in those expressions:

```
new Type1().load(path)
scala> res2: Type1 = Type1@744f0e0b

new Type2().load(path)
scala> res3: Type2 = Type2@77988c45
```

Comment: what is the point of using F-bounded polymorphism if you are overriding in the specific classes? is not your example equal to a over complex factory method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use scala's [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Either):

```
def load(path : String) : Either[Type1, Type2] = {
  this match {
    case t1 : Type1 => Left(someProcessing(t1))
    case t2 : Type2 => Right(someOtherProcessing(t2))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I see that the user has to call either left or right to get the correct object, is there a way to avoid it? For Ex: just call object1.load("path") should directly return me the object of type "object1" instead of object1.load("path").right.get

Comment: scalaz has a construct called disjuction which is "right biased", e.g. it has a map method which will operate on the right value if it is set.  But there's no way to maintain type safety and return 1 of 2 possible values without having some sort of "container" that needs be indexed somehow...

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, you can use

You can use scala's [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Either)

just keep in mind that every method that invokes your method, will need to check which of the types it is returning (using `.map` or pattern matching). Either is usually used like `Either[ErrorType, NormalType]` btw, but of course you can use it however you want

scala cats library has other alternative: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Xor.html

and of course, scalaz also provides an alternative: http://appliedscala.com/blog/2016/scalaz-disjunctions/

As a last resort, don't you can define your own "Either"

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is as simple as returning some instance of the type of context instance... ie `this` then you can just do this,

```
class A() {
  def omg(s: String): this.type = new A()
}
```

And if inheritence is involved,

```
trait A {
  type omgType

  def omg(s: String): omgType
}

class B() extends A {
  override type omgType = this.type

  override def omg(s: String): omgType = new B()
}

class C() extends A {
  override type omgType = this.type

  override def omg(s: String): omgType = new C()
}
```

But if you want more generality then you may want to read the following and apply it there,

The easiest way will be to take inspiration from the `magnet pattern` which was heavily used in Spray.

We can leverage the inspiration to build our custom solution, remember it is neither `pure magnet pattern` nor is `path dependent type` approach. Its a hacky cocktail of both.

So... lets say you want your `def process` to be able to support input parameters of type `Int` and `String` and finally return the respective result.

You will need to define implicit magnets for these types,

```
trait ProcessMagnet {
  type Input
  type Result
  def input: Input
  def process: Result
}

object ProcessMagnetProvider {
  implicit def stringToStringProcessMagnet(string: String): ProcessMagnet = new ProcessMagnet {
    override type Input = String
    override type Result = String

    override def input: Input = string
    // define this for your doing...
    override def process: Result = input + "_omg"
  }
  //... add for all your inputs
  implicit def intToIntProcessMagnet(int: Int): ProcessMagnet = new ProcessMagnet {
    override type Input = Int
    override type Result = Int

    override def input: Input = int
    // define this for your doing...
    override def process: Result = input + 1
  }
}

def process[T](t: T)(implicit pmConverter: T => ProcessMagnet): ProcessMagnet = pmConverter(t)

// now just import our implicit magnets...
import ProcessMagnetProvider._

val intResult: Int = process(5).process.asInstanceOf[Int]

val stringResult: String = process("omg").process.asInstanceOf[String]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about factory method and just defining a trait `loadable` eg:

```
trait Loadable {
  def load(path: String): Loadable
}

class Type1 extends Loadable {
    def load(path: String): Type1 = this
}

class Type2 extends Loadable {
  def load(path: String): Type2 = this
}
object Main {
  def test(): Loadable = {
    new Type1().load("path")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    println(test().getClass)
  }
}
```